# How to make bootstrap datepicker pick last day of the month instead of first day when minViewMode : 1

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm using this version of **Bootstrap DatePicker: http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/** (the **range** type), and i have uploaded my demo on **JSFiddle** on here: http://jsfiddle.net/qs5co179/6/

The relevant JavaScript:

```
$('#sandbox-container .input-daterange').datepicker({
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    minViewMode : 1
});
```

I have set the parameter **minViewMode : 1** so I can view **only months** on calendar instead of full days, the reason is that I want to strict the user to enter:

- **1st day** of the month in: input **name="start"**
- and strict them too to enter only the **last day** of the month in: input **name="end"** (but the default is always 1st day of the month when you click)

For example my data entry that i am looking for like below:

**From: 01/07/2015 - To: 30/09/2015.. in this format (dd/mm/yyyy)**

Now I can't find any parameter to set the calender to pick the **last day** of the month instead of always **1st day** when you click on the month in "To:" field.

**one more thing also** that I want to always make "From:" and "To:" having **3months period and no less**, I want always to make the range 3 months minimum for the entery.

Thanks a lot in advance...

Answer (score 1):

You could attach an event handler to the `changeDate` event ([doc](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/events.html#changedate)), and change the date manually (i.e. add a month, substract a day).

For the date handling part, I would

- Get the date parts
- Increase the month by one, if its December, then change it to January
- Create a new `Date` instance
- `date = date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1)` to get the correct day

The date parts could be exctracted by simple string slicing:

```
var day = str.slice(0,2);
var month = str.slice(3,5);
var year = str.slice(6,10);
```